# does bash if always returns zero?

Tags: bash, if-statement, return-value

do bash if statements always return zero?

I tried

```
$ if false; then echo hi; fi;
$ echo $?
```

and it seems like it.

Comment: Simple counterexample: `if true; then false; fi`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `help if`:

> `if`: `if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi`
>
> Execute commands based on conditional.
>
> The `if COMMANDS` list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, then the
>       `then COMMANDS` list is executed.  Otherwise, each `elif COMMANDS` list is
>       executed in turn, and if its exit status is zero, the corresponding
>       `then COMMANDS` list is executed and the if command completes.  Otherwise,
>       the `else COMMANDS` list is executed, if present.  **The exit status of the
>       entire construct is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero
>       if no condition tested true.**
>
> Exit Status:
>       Returns the status of the last command executed.

(emphasize and formatting mine).

So if there's no `else` part, and if the command to be tested exits with a non-zero code, then the return code is 0.

(But the statement *bash if statements always return zero* is false, as stated in the emphasized part of `help if` included above).

Comment: *exit status of the last command executed*, so it might not return zero: `if true; then ls non-existent-file; fi` followed by `echo $?` gives `1`.

Comment: @cdarke: I was sure somebody was going to argue on this, so I started editing the answer to include a note, until I realized I was paraphrasing `help if`. So I canceled the edit, hoping that readers would actually read the `help if` content that I included.

Comment: @cdarke, especially the emphasized content: ***The exit status of the entire construct is the exit status of the last command executed,*** **or zero if no condition tested true.**

Comment: It's just that your conclusion "*So yes*" implies that "bash statements always return zero", even though you qualify that conclusion I felt your qualification needed underlining.

Comment: @cdarke: you're right, the _yes_ was not appropriate! is the new edit better?